# Django limit query

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a Django query that will limit the returned results to 5 items.  This is easy, except for the fact that the query will not always return 5 items.  In that case, a statement like this (my code) fails:

```
 users = User.objects.filter(username__istartswith = name)[5].only('Person__profile_picture', 'username')
```

If the query only returns a single result, I get an index out of range error.  Is there a way to instruct Django to give me a maximum of 5 results without crashing on me?  Is the standard solution to just wrap everything up in a try block?  Or do I need to write a raw SQL query to accomplish this?

Answer (score 20):

As in doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

For example, this returns the first 5 objects (LIMIT 5):

```
Entry.objects.all()[:5]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
users=User.objects.filter(username__istartswith=name)        
[:5].values(‘Person__profile_picture’,’username’)
```