# value() function showing two time output

Tags: python, django, ajax

```
from hellogymapp.models import CommCenter 
def ajaxAgent(request):
    data = CommCenter.objects.values('inbound_mtd')
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

Comment: the output is coming is : {'inbound_mtd': 1} {'inbound_mtd': 1}

Comment: can you show the output and the model ?

Comment: it mean you have 2 objects in the CommCenter table

Comment: @Linh Nguyenyes but I want this as an output {'inbound_mtd': 1}

Comment: Django query result are show as object, in your case you `getting all objects in your CommCenter table in this case only 2 exists and only showing the inbound_mtd field `,you can read about what django query output [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values) , if you want to only get 1 result from all the object then you have to add the limit to the query (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667785/11225821)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CommCenter.objects.values('inbound_mtd')` this query will list all the records of CommCenter with key `inbound_mtd` and value of it.

Seems like you have total two records of `CommCenter` so all them are listed here.

If you want to filter on some criteria you should

```
CommCenter.objects.filter(inbound_mtd=some_value).values('inbound_mtd')
```

For distinct values do

```
CommCenter.objects.values('inbound_mtd').distinct()
```